# When ASP.NET_SessionId get create

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC framework and I just want to know that when ASP.NET_SessionId get created.I google lots but not found any solution.Because in my project when login page display at that time only it's available even if not login in project.

Answer (score 0):

> can you try to call `Session.Abandon()` or `Session.Clear();` after `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` that will clear current session and recreate new session on the next request.

```
 public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon(); 
        return RedirectToAction("index", "main");
    }
```